# Header with fluid background image on sides, no background in center

Tags: html, css

I need a header that is width:100% and has 3 columns with background images in the 1st and 3rd column:

This solution needs to be cross-browser compatible.

- First column is a background image and is 50% width (not including width of caption)
- Second column is the caption. This has no background (transparent). It's width should not be any greater than it's contents.
- Third column is same as first column.

Using a table this takes 2 seconds: http://jsfiddle.net/aLeyS/

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Caption</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
```

```
table {
    width: 100%;
}
table td:first-child, table td:last-child {
    width: 50%;
    background-image: url(http://fc01.deviantart.net/fs16/i/2007/132/9/4/BW_Striped_Background_Texture_by_Enchantedgal_Stock.jpg);
}
table td:nth-child(2) {
    padding: 0 10px;
    font-size: 30px;
}
```

Without a table this seems to be much trickier.

I've tried using set percentage widths on DIVs inside the parent div, but it always ends up giving the center column more width than it needs, or forcing the caption to wrap if it's not enough percentage.

Again, the center column (caption) should not have any width greater than its content, and it's background needs to be transparent (not white).

Comment: Try using `display:table-cell` on the divs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix this by setting `display:table-cell` on the divs. I've updated your [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aLeyS/2/).

HTML

```
<div class='bg'></div>
<div class='caption'>Caption</div>
<div class='bg'></div>
```

CSS

```
div {
  display: table-cell;
}
div.bg {
  width: 50%;
  background-image: url(http://fc01.deviantart.net/fs16/i/2007/132/9/4/BW_Striped_Background_Texture_by_Enchantedgal_Stock.jpg);
}
div.caption {
  padding: 0 10px;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Comment: This works well, but is there a way without using any type of table cells? Honestly I don't have a problem with tables, but if it's possible without emulating a table cell I'd prefer it.

Comment: Well, in any case you would still be emulating a table cell, you just wouldn't be using the word 'table' in your CSS. :)

Comment: Ya know, this is fine. It's cross-browser compatible and looks nice. Thanks for the answer!